# Is it possible that the chemical reaction $\rm 2KOH + CaCO_3 → Ca(OH)_2 + K_2CO_3$ to be spontaneous?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

1. According to thermodynamics laws, the chemical reaction $\rm 2KOH + CaCO_3 → Ca(OH)_2 + K_2CO_3$ is not spontaneous.
2. I made a  $\rm KOH$ and $\rm CaCO_3$ mixture in water, dried and ground the mixture and did X $-$ ray diffraction and thermogravimetry tests. The results of the two testes showed $\rm Ca(OH)_2$ and $\rm K_2CO_3$ formation.
3. Therefore, according to the thermodynamics theory, the reaction does not occur spontaneously. And according to the tests, the chemical reaction does seem to occur.

So the question is :

Does the chemical reaction $\rm (2KOH + CaCO_3 → Ca(OH)_2 + K_2CO_3)$ occur spontaneously? Yes or no? Why?

Comment: Might this be a better question for [Chemistry.SE]?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert chemistry is applied physics so it is well inside the context of physics

Comment: @JunSeo-He:  Theoretical physics is applied math, but this stack is still a better place for questions about Newton's Laws than [Math.SE] is.  By the same token, this question would probably get better answers on [Chemistry.SE].

Comment: @MichaelSeifert no physics involves chemistry any physics graduate knows very well chemistry ,I agree chemists only study chemistry and it may get better answers on Chemistry Stack Exchange but it can receive good answers here as well I dont see the reason for moving this question to Chemistry Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JunSeo-He "any physics graduate knows very well chemistry" is not correct. I have a PhD in physics and did not even study chemistry in high school. This is like saying "any sociology student knows anthropology". Maybe many of them do, but that is besides the point.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I really like the way you put that. But this 'division of labour' between physics and chemistry is something that has always annoyed me no end. I'm a chemical engineer who loves the C. as  much as the P. (and I'm beginning to think I know more about the P. - others may cheerfully point to my ignorance of course ;-) )

Comment: @Gert, to be clear I don't view it as any more of a division than, say, (graduate and above) the division between high-energy and low-energy theoretical physics. It's just that it's very hard to be an expert at *everything* in the natural sciences :p But I am glad that they teach "integrated science" in my country all the way up to year 11 (age 16) instead of forcing kids to "choose" between e.g. chemistry and physics any earlier than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern chemical theory the term 'spontaneous reaction' doesn't make much sense and isn't often used anymore.

Instead the chemical reaction (e.g.)

$$\text{A}+\text{B} \rightleftharpoons\text{C}+\text{D}\tag{1}$$

is considered an *equilibrium reaction*, so that:

$$K_E=\frac{\alpha_C \alpha_D}{\alpha_A \alpha_B}\tag{2}$$

where $K_E$ is the *equilibrium constant* of $(1)$ and the $\alpha$ are so-called *chemical activities* (in simple, very dilute cases these equate to the more traditional *concentrations*).

If $K\gg 1$ the equilibrium is 'right-leaning', if $K\ll 1$ it is called 'left-leaning'.

It is possible that in your reaction the equilibrium is *sufficiently right-leaning* for **some** $\text{Ca(OH)}_2$ and $\text{K}_2\text{CO}_{3}$ to form in your conditions. **But you need to be very certain of your experimental/analytical conditions.**

> Yes or no? Why?

So, as so often it's not really a 'yes or no' question.

Comment: Did you mean to have "B" on both the left-hand and right-hand sides of your reaction?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Hi Michael. It's been edited now. Thanks for proof-reading!

Comment: As a chemist, this gets my upvote. But I hate that equilibrium sign.

Comment: The double arrow ($\iff$)? I don't know where to find a better one?

Comment: Yes! We like the double “fish hook” barbed arrows. I’m guessing MathJax has it, but I use MathType, which has equilibria signs with both equal length and various unequal length barbed arrows. This can be used to indicate qualitatively that equilibrium lies more toward one side than the other. Just a tiny quibble! ;-)

Comment: @Gert About the double fish hook/harpoon: Chemistry SE uses preinstalled mhchem MathJax package, Physics SE may have to use explicitly `$\require{mhchem}$` $\require{mhchem}$ Then we use e.g. `$$\ce{CH3COOH + C2H5OH  <=> CH3COOC2H5 + H2O}$$` to get $$\ce{CH3COOH + C2H5OH  <=> CH3COOC2H5 + H2O}$$ The double arrow above  has different meaning - tautomerization, like a molecule having virtually  multiple forms.

Answer (score 0):

A physics domain being a superset to the chemistry also means knowledge of chemists about chemistry is generally a superset of knowledge of physicists about it.

The above reaction is in fact the set of 4 dissolution equilibrii, characterized by their respective solubility products ( [Libretexts.org](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Equilibria/Solubilty/Solubility_Product_Constant%2C_Ksp) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_equilibrium) ):$\require{mhchem}$

\begin{align}
\ce{Ca(OH)2(s) &<=> Ca^2+(aq) + 2 OH^-(aq)}\\
\ce{CaCO3(s) &<<=> Ca^2+(aq) + CO3^2-(aq)}\\
\ce{KOH(s) &<=> K+(aq) + OH-(aq)}\\
\ce{K2CO3(s) &<=> 2 K+(aq) + CO3^2-(aq)}
\end{align}

With the addition that for high [ionic strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_strength), activities should be used instead of concentrations.

Extremely high activity of $\ce{OH-}$ in concentrated $\ce{KOH}$ may cause precipitation of $\ce{Ca^2+}$ ions, making $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ effectively less soluble than $\ce{CaCO3}$, leading to formation of $\ce{Ca(OH)2(s)}$ and later $\ce{K2CO3(s)}$.